# PCA for sparse matrix

Tags: r, pca

I want to use PCA for a sparse matrix(which represents images),420000*1784 size ,about 2% non-zero entries,and the principal function tells me that there is a lot NA value in its egien values and egien matrix ,what is the reason for that? is there another function to deal with such situations ?Or I need to write a function to do this ?

Comment: Please make it reproductible ? ( == code + data )

Comment: Have you done any prior search on the subject? I found this http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35185/dimensionality-reduction-svd-or-pca-on-a-large-sparse-matrix that seems relevant.

Comment: Besides 
[`irlba`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352771/svd-of-very-large-matrix-in-r-program/17354248),
you can also use `igraph::arpack`, as in 
[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966748/computing-eigenvectors-of-a-sparse-matrix-in-r/).

Comment: Thank you for your help.And thanks to the links given by   Roman Luštrik ,I know how to deal with my problem